# Cassandra failing when writing data

Tags: cassandra, garbage-collection, jvm

I'm trying to load data into Cassandra and it is failing.  I'm running on a single node (laptop) but I see the same behavior in a small cluster (3-5 nodes).  I'm running Cassandra 3.9 with default settings.

I'm writing from two threads using using the DataStax Java driver 3.0.0.  I'm writing rows that have 50KB rows with 5-10K columns.  The total dataset will be about 40GB on disk.  I'm writing 5 rows concurrently/thread.

After inserting for a while, I start to get write timeouts:

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.WriteTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during write query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 replica were required but only 0 acknowledged the write)
```

I retry with exponential backoff.  Eventually the writes stop making forward progress.  At this point, I'm seeing very long GC pauses:

```
WARN  [Service Thread] 2017-01-11 19:04:54,529 GCInspector.java:282 - ConcurrentMarkSweep GC in 4139ms.  CMS Old Gen: 3456106376 -> 3455729576; Par Eden Space: 671088640 -> 670388064; Par Survivor Space: 83886080 -> 58722784
WARN  [Service Thread] 2017-01-11 19:04:58,692 GCInspector.java:282 - ConcurrentMarkSweep GC in 4010ms.  CMS Old Gen: 3456105584 -> 3455769528; Par Survivor Space: 83886080 -> 62960320
```

At this point, it looks like all the time is being spent in GC.  Even if I kill the write job, Cassandra doesn't appear to recover.  It eventually dies with an OutOfMemoryError.  I lowered the memtable space to 32MB:

```
memtable_heap_space_in_mb: 32
memtable_offheap_space_in_mb: 32
```

and that might have fixed the OOM error (although maybe I'm just not waiting long enough).

I was hoping that Cassandra + exponential backoff would throttle the writer to some maximum equilibrium write speed, but that doesn't seem to be happening.  Is that an unrealistic expectation for Cassandra?  I can rate limit in the writer, but I don't know what metric is reasonable to rate limit on.  Any ideas?

Comment: My behavior looks a lot like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21715622/large-writes-cause-instability-in-cassandra-ring.  Point 4 in RussS's answer seems relevant.  This still doesn't explain how to throttle write speed.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical problem with Cassandra clusters.

I see this in two ways:

- It's *cassandra clients* responsibility to throttle down writes in order to not overload the cluster. This is called *backpressure*
- It's *engineers* responsibility to design the cluster to fit the SLA of the application and support the write speed (and latency) needed.

Since you may not have idea on how your cluster will perform, the only option you have is to apply *backpressure*. Throttle down the writes to a reasonable value at client-level. This value heavily depends on you hardware (well, and software) configuration. Try with a ballbark value (eg 3k op/s), and raise this value until you find the write speed that starts to overload your cluster. You'll find what's the rate that your cluster supports (with your specific workload!). If it's not enough for your application then expand your cluster with more nodes.